# CSS Gradient Restarting in Multiple Boxes

Tags: css, colors, gradient, linear-gradients

Here's a link to my jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/inthenameofmusik/ddto077m/5/

The gradient restarts over and over in every box or element it seems. I'm not sure what's wrong with my CSS. Any help appreciated.

```
body {
background: linear-gradient(#1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

I'm sure this is a simple fix, sorry for the CSS beginner-ness of this question.

Comment: add background-repeat: no-repeat; & background-attachment: fixed;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `html, body {height:100%;}` to your style to force the browser to render the html parent tag at full height. Currently it's rendering only about 100px tall and the body background is repeating.

See this [update fiddle for example](http://jsfiddle.net/ddto077m/7/).